# Spring Data JPA Query with Projection and List creates invalid SQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to retrieve only a certain portion of data using a JPA Query and Projection.  Here is the query:

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends CrudRepository<Company, Integer> {
    @Query("select co.companyID as companyid, co.companyName as companyname, co.companyAbbr as companyabbr, co.flags as flags from Company co order by companyName asc")
    List<CompanyWithFlags> getAllCompaniesWithFlags();
}
```

Here is the projection:

```
public interface CompanyWithFlags {
    Integer getCompanyid();
    String getCompanyname();
    String getCompanyabbr();
    List<CompanyFlag> getFlags();
}
```

Here is the Company entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="companies.companies")
public class Company implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int companyID;
    private String companyName;
    private String companyAbbr;
    ...
    private List<CompanyFlag> flags = new ArrayList<>();

    public Company() {}

    @Id
    @Column(name="pk_companyid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonView(View.AllCompaniesView.class)
    public int getCompanyID() {
        return companyID;
    }

    public void setCompanyID(int companyID) {
        this.companyID = companyID;
    }

    @Column(name="companyname", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(72)")
    @JsonView(View.AllCompaniesView.class)
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    @Column(name="companyabbr", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(8)")
    @JsonView(View.AllCompaniesView.class)
    public String getCompanyAbbr() {
        return companyAbbr;
    }

    public void setCompanyAbbr(String companyAbbr) {
        this.companyAbbr = companyAbbr;
    }

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="companies.co_flags",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="fk_companyid", referencedColumnName="pk_companyid"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="fk_flagid", referencedColumnName="pk_flagid"))
    @JsonView(View.AllCompaniesView.class)
    public List<CompanyFlag> getFlags() {
        return flags;
    }

    public void setFlags(List<CompanyFlag> flags) {
        this.flags = flags;
    }
}
```

If I leave the `CompanyFlag` out of the query and projection, everything works fine.  If I don't write the query, but instead just use:

```
List<CompanyWithFlags> findAllByOrderByCompanyNameAsc();
```

then I get the data as desired, but there is a very long list of other (unnecessary) queries that are generated as well.

As it is, hibernate (5.2.14) generates this query:

```
select 
  company0_.pk_companyid as col_0_0_, 
  company0_.companyname as col_1_0_, 
  company0_.companyabbr as col_2_0_, 
  . as col_3_0_, 
  companyfla2_.pk_flagid as pk_flagi1_9_, 
  companyfla2_.fk_categoryid as fk_categ3_9_, 
  companyfla2_.flagname as flagname2_9_ 
from companies.companies company0_ 
inner join companies.co_flags flags1_ on company0_.pk_companyid=flags1_.fk_companyid 
inner join companies.config_flags companyfla2_ on flags1_.fk_flagid=companyfla2_.pk_flagid 
order by companyName asc
```

Obviously, the problem is `. as col_3_0_`, but I can't figure out why that is being generated or how to get rid of it.  Can anyone explain why hibernate is adding that and what I can do differently in the repository to achieve the desired data in an efficient manner?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like a bug in the Spring Data JPA - see my report: [DATAJPA-1299](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1299).

To workaround this try to use a query method with 'distinct' as following:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "flags")
List<CompanyWithFlags> findDistinctAllByOrderByCompanyNameAsc();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it still produced a whole bunch of extra queries related to the other properties in the Company entity.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find a query which worked, although not quite like I expected.  Here is the query:

```
@Query("select co.companyID as companyid, co.companyName as companyname, co.companyAbbr as companyabbr, fl as flags from Company co left join co.flags fl order by companyName asc")
List<CompanyWithFlags> getAllCompaniesWithFlags();
```

I was wanting/expecting a result that was in the format:

```
companyid: 1,
companyabbr: "ABC",
companyname: "Alpha Beta Company",
flags: [
  {
    flagID: 1,
    flagName: "Flag 1"
  },
  {
    flagID: 2,
    flagName: "Flag 2"
  }
]
```

However, the query produces a result like this:

```
companyid: 1,
companyabbr: "ABC",
companyname: "Alpha Beta Company",
flags: [
  {
    flagID: 1,
    flagName: "Flag 1"
  }
],
companyid: 1,
companyabbr: "ABC",
companyname: "Alpha Beta Company",
flags: [
  {
    flagID: 2,
    flagName: "Flag 2"
  }
]
```

I am using Angular on the front end, and it was able to read this correctly to achieve my desired end result, so this query is working for me.  It produces the minimal amount of SQL queries in Hibernate.